# Add html elements randomly inside rows

Tags: jquery, random, repeat, tabular

I have a large grid, meant for a time line view. What I want is that the next divs are randomly added to the rows (not all rows), so that the grid is pretty filled with colored boxes. The divs are:

```
    <div class="bar ganttRed" id="b4" style="width: 330px;">
        <div class="label" style="color: rgb(191, 191, 191); float: left; margin-left: 23.7px;"> 2836DE
        </div>
    </div>
```

and

```
    <div class="bar ganttGreen" id="b6" style="width: 66px;">
        <div class="label" style="color: rgb(61, 61, 61); float: left; margin-left: 14px;"> 2142 FG
        </div>
    </div>
```

I just do not know how this should be done.

[And check out my Jsfiddle for viewing the html grid.](http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/4fpcgLqy/)

Comment: Whats the requirement ?

Comment: I just want to fill the grid randomly with the two colored divs, but the boxes must not overlap eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want but you should get the idea...

```
$('.div-table-row').each(function () {

    var color = getRandomColor();
    var bar = '<div class="bar" style="background-color: ' + color + '; width: ' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 80) + 'px;"><div class="label">' + color + '</div></div>';
    $('.div-table-td:eq(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + ')', this).html(bar);
});

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/4fpcgLqy/2/)</kbd>

**Edit:**

2 bars mode:

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/4fpcgLqy/5/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. How can I repeat multiple bars on each row?

Comment: Is there a clever way to show for example 20 bars in a row without duplicating code?

Comment: You said that the bars should not overlap. How do you want to display 20 bars in a row that contains 18 elements?

Comment: Yes but let say for the sake of argument we have 200 rows instead of 18.

Comment: Well not really with the code I provided. You would need to count how many empty space remains, and continue to fill...